# Увеличение высоты поля ввода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите, возможно ли в textarea или input-е сделать так, чтобы при достижении правого борта (то есть границы поля), после того, как идет перенос на следующую строку текст не съезжал вверх, а вместо этого увеличивалась Высота поля? 
Возможна ли такое реализовать без js, а если не возможно, то подскажите в какую сторону копать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Без JS нельзя**, но можно вместо инпута использовать обычный элемент и стилизовать его под инпут:

```css
.input{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-color: #666 #ccc #ccc #666;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ccc inset;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input" contenteditable="true">Введите текст здесь</div>
```

Comment: Я бы добавил `.input::before {
        content: attr(title);
    }
    .input:focus::before {
        content: '';
    }
`
и `title='Введите текст здесь'` в `<div />`